# Is possible to connect to Databricks Data Base in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks

Context: I'm trying to make a report to monitoring all the processes built in a DataBricks environment. So, I need to get Notebooks and Workflows data (cluster where is attached, user who created the process and how many times has failed, etc.).

Problem: I need to get the data automatically, so in order to reach this goal, I've wondering if is possible to connect to DataBricks database or there is an API. If is possible, what would be the process? Could you guide me?

Comment: Here's API: https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/introduction. You can use it to get detailed info about virtually everything around Databricks instance. Is this something you were looking for?

Comment: Shure, @Kombajnzbożowy! this is what i'm looking for, just a couple of questions. How can I get DATABRICKS_HOST and DATABRICKS_TOKEN?

Answer (score 0):

The Databricks host is the URL of your Databricks workspace.

It will be like below
`https://<your-databricks-instance>.cloud.databricks.com`

and you can find in the workspace link in chrome.
[image]

You can also get that in **JDBC/ODBC** under cluster Advanced options.

[image]

Now you need to create access token.

Got to **user settings** at the top right menu.

[image]

There in **Developer** option click manage for **Access token**.

[image]

There you will get option called **Generate new token**.
Click on it and copy the new token.

Next, you can use below python code for getting details of workspace, cluster and workflows.

```
import requests

DATABRICKS_TOKEN = "Your_token"
DATABRICKS_HOST = "Your_host"
workspace_endpoint = f"{DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/workspace/list?path=/"
cluster_endpoint = f"{DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/clusters/list"
workflow_endpoint = f"{DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/jobs/list"

headers = {
"Authorization": f"Bearer {DATABRICKS_TOKEN}"
}

workspace_response = requests.get(workspace_endpoint, headers=headers)
cluster_response = requests.get(cluster_endpoint, headers=headers)
workflow_response = requests.get(workflow_endpoint, headers=headers)

print("Workspace................")
print(workspace_response.json())
print("Cluster................")
print(cluster_response.json())
print("Workflow................")
print(workflow_response.json())
```

Output:

[image]

Similarly, you can make this request using `curl` command or `postman` Gui interface.